# neo4j: No qualifying bean of type found for dependency

Tags: java, spring, maven, neo4j

I'm trying to run this example:
https://spring.io/guides/gs/accessing-data-neo4j/
I'm using Maven as build tool.
I get error as below:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-maven-plugin:1.3.3.RELEASE:run (default-cli) on project gs-accessing-data-neo4j: An exception occurred while running. null: InvocationTargetException: Error creating bean with name 'demo' defined in hello.Application: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor argument with index 0 of type [hello.PersonRepository]: No qualifying bean of type [hello.PersonRepository] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {}; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [hello.PersonRepository] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {} -> [Help 1]
```

What is the problem?

This is my PersonRepository.java file:

```
package hello;

import java.util.List;
import org.springframework.data.neo4j.config.EnableNeo4jRepositories;

import org.springframework.data.repository.CrudRepository;

@EnableNeo4jRepositories(basePackageClasses=CrudRepository.class)
public interface PersonRepository extends CrudRepository<Person, String>
{

    Person findByName(String name);

    List<Person> findByTeammatesName(String name);

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you read the tutorial carefully, you'll see:

> In the configuration, you need to add the `@EnableNeo4jRepositories` annotation as well as extend the `Neo4jConfiguration` class to conveniently spin up needed components.
>
> By default, `@EnableNeo4jRepositories` will scan the current package for any interfaces that extend one of Spring Data’s repository interfaces. Use it’s `basePackageClasses=MyRepository.class` to safely tell Spring Data GemFire to scan a different root package by type if your project layout has multiple projects and its not finding your repositories.
>
> One piece that’s missing is the graph database service bean. In this case, you are using the `EmbeddedGraphDatabase`, which creates and reuses a file-based data store at `accessingdataneo4j.db`.

As such, you need to write a class that will add the configuration of the Sprint Boot application. Let's call it `ApplicationConfig.java`. Putting into code what the tutorial is saying, we come up with:

```
package hello;

import org.neo4j.graphdb.GraphDatabaseService;
import org.neo4j.graphdb.factory.GraphDatabaseFactory;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.data.neo4j.config.EnableNeo4jRepositories;
import org.springframework.data.neo4j.config.Neo4jConfiguration;

@Configuration
@EnableNeo4jRepositories
class ApplicationConfig extends Neo4jConfiguration {

    public ApplicationConfig() {
        setBasePackage("hello");
    }

    @Bean
    GraphDatabaseService graphDatabaseService() {
        return new GraphDatabaseFactory().newEmbeddedDatabase("accessingdataneo4j.db");
    }
}
```

If you add this class to your `hello` package, the application will run correctly.

Note that you should keep the `PersonRepository` as it is defined in the tutorial, which is like the following:

```
package hello;

import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.data.repository.CrudRepository;

public interface PersonRepository extends CrudRepository<Person, String> {

    Person findByName(String name);

    List<Person> findByTeammatesName(String name);

}
```

---

As a side-note, you can see its full code on the [Spring GitHub repo](https://github.com/spring-guides/gs-accessing-data-neo4j/blob/master/complete).